# Run ssis package with dynamic parameters from stored procedure or Job Agent

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, ssms, sql-agent-job

I have deployed a SSIS project into my server. There is a master package that should be execute with parameters. The parameters are datetime type.

I need to pass two each parameter the value: of Actual date - 1. I setted up a Sql server job but as i understand i cann pass there only a static value

[image]

How can i pass dynamic values to the job? Maybe can i run the package with SP procedure and set the value?

Anyway i will be appreciate if you can write to me an explanation.

Comment: You can't; parameters defined in a task must be literals not expressions or derived some other way.

Comment: Can you talk us through how you envision this working? You have a job, which runs in the background without human interaction but you also want a thing to prompt for values to run?

Comment: Otherwise, you're on the right track with creating a procedure that requires the input parameter. Script out a package execution and stub in the the run-time parameter there

Comment: @billinkc so i thought that when the job runs it can calculate the parameters in an expression. Do you know how can i call a ssis package and pass parameters?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite well versed in all things SSIS so I can describe how to pass parameters to the execution of an SSIS Package. What I cannot yet do, is answer your question because I do not have a clear understanding of what you need to have happen. Look at the How to Ask section of the Help Center https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @billinkc Sorry because i could not explain well what i wanted. Anyway i resolve my question)
I execute my ssis package using catalog.set_object_parameter_value and catalog.create_execution in SP